# Does the ICS Email app allow you to get notifications on folders other than inbox?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, email, notifications, imap

I have set on a IMAP account on my ICS android. I have some of the mails filtered to go to different folders. Is it possible to receive notifications the other folders? It is annoying, when I read some important messages one month late.

The is another similar [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/how-can-i-get-push-notifications-for-emails-in-sub-folders), but it is mainly for gingerbread, and also they end up discussing mostly the gmail app. Feel free to close as duplicate, if you choose this as not fitting.