# Can I get a notification when an email arrives in a sub folder?

Tags: email

I have a number of sub-folders set up on my work email with rules moving certain emails into these folders automatically.  On the Galaxy S3 I can see these folders, and can 'auto-sync' the folder, but how do I set it up so that I get a notification when a new email arrives into it?

Comment: which email client are you currently using? The stock Email or Gmail or something else?

Comment: Related: [Does the ICS Email app allow you to get notifications on folders other than inbox?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23833/does-the-ics-email-app-allow-you-to-get-notifications-on-folders-other-than-inbo)

Answer (score 6):

There are many email apps for Android, each one should have an option within the app itself where you can check or uncheck to be notified of a new email arrival.

**This list covers the most popular ones:**

## Email

Allows you to have a notification on the status bar, when activated within the application:

1. Access the application;
2. Tap your device "home" button;
3. Tap "Account Settings";
4. Scroll your way to "Notification settings";
5. Tick the checkbox for "Email notifications".

## Gmail

Allows you to have a notification on the status bar for each one of the configured accounts. Can be activated within the application:

1. Access the application;
2. Tap your device "home" button;
3. Tap "more";
4. Tap "Settings";
5. Tap over the desired account;
6. Scroll your way to "Notification settings";
7. Tick the checkbox for "Email notifications".

## K-9 Mail

Allows you to have a notification on the status bar for each one of the configured accounts. Can be activated within the application:

1. Access the application;
2. Tap your device "home" button;
3. Tap "more";
4. Tap "Accounts";
5. Long Tap over the desired account;
6. From the popup, tap "Account settings";
7. Scroll your way to "Notifications" and tap it;
8. Tick the checkbox for "New mail notifications".

## MailDroid

Allows you to have a notification on the status bar, when activated within the application:

1. Access the application;
2. Tap your device "home" button;
3. Tap "Preferences";
4. Scroll your way to "Notifications" and tap it;
5. Select the icon for the status bar from the dropdown;
6. Tick the checkbox for "Show separate notification", aditionally you can tick the checkbox for "show once";

## Yahoo! Mail

Allows you to have a notification on the status bar for each one of the configured accounts. Can be activated within the application:

1. Access the application;
2. Tap your device "home" button;
3. Tap "Options";
4. Tap the desirable account;
5. Tap "Notification Settings";
6. Tick the checkbox for "Show in Status Bar".

## Hotmail

Allows you to have a notification on the status bar, when activated within the application:

1. Access the application;
2. Tap your device "home" button;
3. Tap "Account Settings";
4. Scroll your way to "General Settings" and tap it;
5. Scroll your way to "Notifications and Alerts" and tap it;
6. Tap "Email Notifications";
7. Tick the checkbox for "Message Notification".

---

**Notes:**

- Some Email apps, in order to notify you of the arrival of new mail, need to have the "auto-sync" and the "Background Data" active on your phone settings:

  This options are found on your device settings, under "Accounts & sync".
- "Tick the checkbox" stands for having the checkbox with a green tick on it. The gray tick is the disable status.
- If your email app isn't present on the above list, feel free to @Zuul me and I'll be glad to add it to the list.
- Only email app with Notification capabilities will be present.

Comment: Are these notifications for all folders, inbox only, or folders of your choosing?

Comment: From testing the above, I'm not finding his solution working for subfolders in Gmail so I assume it only works with Inbox.

Comment: @Will.Beninger I believe that only for inbox, at least for the Gmail App, others I can't say for sure since I'm no longer using them!

Comment: This does not answer the question regarding notifications of subfolders on Android for GMail using the stock Gmail App

Answer (score 5):

There is no option to set notifications on sub folders using the stock email app. You can set each folder to sync but only the inbox will throw a notification. There are some email apps that will do it though. Touchdown does for sure but it is a $20 app. K9 is another popular email app but I have not tested for this functionality.

Comment: Do you have any reference for your claim? And which email app are you talking about?

Comment: This is no longer true

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **Gmail** App:

### Will notify only selected sub-folder

1. Open "*Settings*"
2. Select Account
3. Select "*Manage Labels*" Or "*Folder sync settings*" in *Exchange* mail
4. Select Label (Sub-Folder) to get notifications for
5. Verify Sync is applied (All or last 4 days)
6. Check "*Label notifications*"
7. You can also check "*Vibrate*" and/or "*Notify for every message*" as well.

This Information tested with *Gmail App* in the following versions:

- 4.5.2-714156
- 6.11.27.141872707
- 8.7.1.204805656.release

Comment: What does **Notify for every message** do? How is it different from **Label Notifications**?

Comment: Turns out that when **Notify for every message** is not turned on, you receive a sound notification only for the 1st message in a messages group (Gmail groups messages in the notification screen and titles them **<n> new messages**) until you clear the notifications, and then on a new message you get a sound notification again. If it's turned on, then you'll get a sound notification on every message no matter the grouping.

Comment: Confirmed Working

Comment: I do not have "Label notifications". Gmail 2019.11.03.280318276.release on Android 9. (This is an Exchange account.)

Answer (score 2):

Since Google didn't seem to work on this feature, I've implemented it myself. You can download my app and my code changes in this [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1655328&page=3).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this on my Droid (running version 4.4.4) by updating the Outlook rule, instructing to flag the messages that were automatically being moved to the sub-folder.  I now receive email notifications on my phone (using the stock app), even though the messages are going to a folder outside of the Inbox.

[image: Screenshot for Reference]

Answer (score 1):

In the Email app in my Android 4.4.2, there is now an option for **Folder sync settings** in each e-mail account. By setting a particular folder to **Push** instead of **Manual** sync, I receive notifications when e-mails arrive in a sub-folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

K-9 (an open source, very secure free mail client) does exactly this.

In fact, you can specify that certain folders can show up in your primary list, only certain folders receive notifications when messages received, or only certain folders participate in push.

Furthermore, you can specify these settings on an individual basis based on the concepts of tiers (classes). This is kind of like first and second class favorite folders; you can force subfolders to be displayed above your main Inbox, for instance.

For example, you can specify that a folder is a first-tier notification folder, but a second-tier visibility folder. You can also specify push/sync tier membership. (All of these settings are independent and very controllable, but they are just a click away in each folder's settings.)

To go further, you can set certain folders to notify based on their notification tier level (first, second, or none).

See the documentation for K-9 folders here:
https://k9mail.github.io/documentation/settings/folder.html
https://k9mail.github.io/documentation/folders.html

This documentation is OLD! In current versions of K-9, there is now support for Folder Notification classes as well, so you can specify that some folders notify and some do not.

One thing to be aware of: in the main menu (button menu), you will see an entry called "Folders", which takes you to your folder list. That's not what you want. First, select a folder, and then, while viewing on that folder message list, select the menu button again and choose Settings/Folder; that's where you do the individual folder settings. I believe Notification settings for folder tiers are actually under Settings/Account or Settings/Global.

One great feature that is not currently implemented would be setting a different notification sound for different folders.