# Unable to view emails in folders other than inbox

Tags: email, push-notifications, hotmail

I am using [Hotmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotmail.Z7&feature=search_result) app developed by "Microsoft + Seven" to read emails. I have many folders other than inbox to segregate my emails. There are rules set in web version of Hotmail, that moves the incoming emails to respective folders. These rules are working fine and I observe all my moved emails correctly in web version.

However, my [Android client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotmail.Z7&feature=search_result) notifies me and displays only about the new emails in my Inbox. I had selected those other folders in the app to download email:

[image]

But still, I neither do not get any notifications on these folders nor any email when I open the folder in the client. When I open the folder I get "No messages" message in the screen, through there are messages. When I press "Check email" option in the context menu while I am viewing the folder, a toast message "Check email request sent" is displayed and goes off with no emails shown.

Though I am not worried about the notification about the new emails in the folders other than inbox, I do want to read them in the client. Presently. I am doing this by opening web version in a browser.

I have seen the following questions which are close but not to be considered as duplicate.

1. [How can I sync all folders from an Exchange server (not just the
   Inbox)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17004/how-can-i-sync-all-folders-from-an-exchange-server-not-just-the-inbox) I am not using an exchange server. I am using Hotmail POP or IMap servers.
2. [How can I get push notifications for emails in
   sub-folders?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15212/how-can-i-get-push-notifications-for-emails-in-sub-folders) This talks about Gmail and my Gmail client is working perfectly fine. But in Gmail, there are no folders only labels.
3. [Can I get a notification when an email arrives in
   a sub folder?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26956/can-i-get-a-notification-when-an-email-arrives-in-a-sub-folder) I am not much worried about notification. But as said in @Zuul's explanation regarding Hotmail, all done; no fun.

I haven't tried other email apps including stock app in Android 2.3.3 LG V20G P500.